Author and year in parentheses
I want in front of the theorem to be written as the  following:
Theorem1(Stone, 1932; Banach, 1933)
With a command that I wrote The output is as follows:
Theorem1(64;2)
But reference numbers come in front of the theorem.
What command I should use that  its output  is like the above

Welcome to TeX.SE. The title of your query mentions square parentheses, yet in the body of your query you employ round parentheses. You also mention some theorem, yet you provide no information as to how the theorem could be generated or how the citation call-outs might be related to the theorem. Please clarify your methods and objectives.

If and how author-year citations are possible depends on the bibliography packages you load and your other bibliography- and citation-related setup. If you use biblatex as the tag suggests \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} will generate author-year citations and \autocite{sigfridsson,worman} will cite the two works in round brackets/parentheses.

Unfortunately, we really need to see an example document that shows what you are doing in order to help you. There are several different implementations of citations and the bibliography in LaTeX and if and how the output can be changed depends on the method you use. Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 to see how you can come up with a usable example document.
